# How do I stop reading from stdin console in C

Tags: c

I am new in C programming. While I was trying to code, I came across this problem. Sorry, if the solution is obvious and I posted it here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int T = 2;
    while(T--){

        c = getc(stdin);
        while( (c != '\n') && (c != EOF)){
           // do some work
        c = getc(stdin);    
       }
    }
return 0;
}
```

what I want is like if I have multiple string inputs in multiple lines, e.g.,

> Hithere
>
> howareyou
>
> Iamgood

And then, if after reading characters "**hith**", the while loop is broken then the next character to be read by **fgetc(stdin)** should be from the second line(**howareyou**) NOT the characters from "**Hithere**".

> Actually, I will be given 3 input strings in 3 different lines. And I
>   have to check the strings individually for some special character. And
>   if the character is found then I will print that it is found and
>   immediately stop checking any further characters in that string.
>   Similarly, check for the next string, then next string and so on.

Many many thanks in advance. Please help me.

Comment: Your `while` condition should be `((c != '\n') && (c != EOF))` not `((c != '\n')|| (c != EOF))`

Comment: yes. Thanks it should be && not ||.
Actually, I will be given 3 input strings in 3 different lines. And I have to check the strings individually for some special character. And if the character is found then I will print that it is found and immediately stop checking any further characters in that string. 
Similarly, check for the next string, then next string and so on.

So how to achieve this?

Comment: To check for any character within a string, you can use `strchr` and to find a sub-string in a string you can use `strstr`.

Comment: I don't want to store the string to any array or in any other form. I just want to read the characters in the string directly from 'stdin' and and if my desired condition is met then I would stop reading any further characters in in that **particular line** and then begin reading from the next line in stdin to check for the same condition.

So, I think 'strchr' or 'strstr' could not solve my intention.

Comment: Why do you want to do that, when taking input as a string makes your problem simpler?

Answer (score 2):

The logic in this line is incorrect.

```
    while( (c != '\n')|| (c != EOF)){
```

Change it to:

```
    while( (c != '\n') && (c != EOF)){
```

Answer (score 1):

For your second question (in the future, please only post one question per question!) you might want to use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a line, and then get characters from the read line.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. From next time I will ask one question at a time.
But using fgets() and then getting characters from it would be abit more time consuming. Is there no way to get limited characters from stdin without storing the entire string ?

Comment: @user3606997 It's only time-consuming because you might have to write more code, from the run-time point of view it will hardly be noticeable worse (most likely it might even be better). The only other way is to read a character at a time (like you do now) and when you break out of the inner loop then do a `fgets` call to get the rest of the line, it has the downside of you doing maybe many more function calls in the loop, compared to a single call followed by pretty fast memory access in my first solution.

Comment: That means there is no way to achieve my original goal ? i.e., avoid any extra character reading and start reading from the beginning of the next string in the next loop iteration.
Because my input strings will be very large like 100000 characters. So reading all would be COMPARATIVELY slow. Thanks in advance!
Also, if not possible, then please suggest what to use in that case like fgets() or scanf to character array ?? I want my code to have a run time of 0.00 secs.

Comment: could you please tell me a way by which I can allocate memory only sufficient enough to store each string dynamically even if I don't know the length of each string ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user3606997 You know that even theoretically you can't have a program with *zero* runtime? And if you don't know the length of the lines you read, you can't use `fgets` and have to use e.g. `fgetc` to read and ignore characters until you hit a newline. There's simply no way around it.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the operating system you are running this program. For example, in Windows a line ends with `\r\n` while on Unix, it ends in `\n`.